# IE8- jQuery html on non-HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm working with some XML from a database and parsing it with jQuery.  This works fine everywhere except for IE8-, which I need to support.  I have elements like `<stem>`, and I can get IE to somewhat support them by adding

```
document.createElement('stem');
```

etc. The problem is that some of these elements may contain HTML that I need to append to another element on the page.  Something like

```
$("#page-element").append($xml.find('stem'));
```

I can use `$xml.find('stem').text()` just fine, but whenever I use `.html` or any DOM-manipulation methods (including the `.append` line above), IE gives the very helpful error

> Unspecified error (line 4 of jquery-min.js)

Depending upon what I try to do, I can get

> Unable to get value of the property 'replace': object is null or undefined (line 4)

instead.

Is there any workaround for getting HTML from non-HTML elements (and even HTML5 elements) in IE8-?

Comment: Have you tried [`htn5shiv`](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv)?

Comment: @undefined these are not all html5 elements, I just assume that those elements would have the same problem

Comment: I recently had this problem in IE8, markup was invalid, at least for IE, only missing `/` in `<div>`, it seems IE8 handles markup strictly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8- will allow you to get the *text* value of these non-HTML elements without complaining.  You can then apply this as normal html with the `.html` method, interestingly enough:

```
$("#bar").html($("stem").text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/UTHpy/